# Wireless Network completely disabled

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I have read many posts and the answers provided don't seem to help me.
I have ran many commands and pasted them below so hopefully will cover the basic questions about my system and what i am experiencing.  As you can see, I have no wired connection anymore.  I had to move my PC so can;t connect physically anymore.
Your assistance will be most appreciated.

---

Hey WILF thanks very much for your assistance and apologies for the delay.
I decided to remove all the old stuff, as i think it will be irrelevant now.
I have rerun the script but lspci gives me nothing to do with network. See below for results (i removed the details and only provided the headers):

salvador@salvador:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[first it shows] CPUID
[but quickly turns to ] PCI (sysfs)
[but after a few seconds, it turns to nothing]

```
--------------------------

salvador@salvador:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[same as above]

--------------------------

salvador@salvador:~$ sudo lspci -v
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation
...
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
...
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
...
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)
...
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a3) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
...
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a3) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
...
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
...
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
...
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
...
00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)
...
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
...
00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
...
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
...
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
...
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
...
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
...
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
...
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
...
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
...
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
...
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
...
```

---

Once again, thanks you very much for your help thus far and your very clear instructions.

Comment: Is this a USB wifi card, or one in the  computer?

Comment: There are a few wireless devices that are attached to an internal USB bus. Please edit your question to add the result of: lsusb

Comment: First of all thanks very much for the reply.  it is really appreciated.

See below:
salvador@salvador:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c312 Logitech, Inc. DeLuxe 250 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c45:612c Microdia PC Camera (SN9C110)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade

Answer (score 0):

As you have no network connection, you will have to install the packages manually. You wil have to download the `.deb` files, and install with `dpkg`.

From the following links you can download the `.deb` files on another machine, and then copy the files other to the one without any internet - select the `32bit` links:

- [`ethtool`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/ethtool)
- [`lshw`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/lshw)
- [`lshw-gtk`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/universe/base/lshw-gtk) - you probably won't need this, it just provides a graphical interface for `lshw`.
- [`rfkill`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/rfkill)

To install the packages, right-click on one and select <kbd>Copy</kbd>

Open a terminal, and right click and select 'Paste Filenames'.
If you don't have 'Paste Filenames', see the small print below. You should get something like:

```
'/home/wmobbs/Downloads Folder/lshw_02.15-2_i386.deb'
```

<sub>If you paste ordinarily You will likely get something like this:</sub>

```
file:///home/wmobbs/Downloads%20Folder/lshw_02.15-2_i386.deb
```

<sub>remove the `file://`, swap the `%20`s for spaces s, and add quotes:</sub>

```
'/home/wmobbs/Downloads Folder/lshw_02.15-2_i386.deb'
```

Now add `sudo dpkg -i` at the beginning, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
sudo dpkg -i '/home/wmobbs/Downloads Folder/lshw_02.15-2_i386.deb'
```

That should install the package, then repeat that for the other required packages.

If you need any dependencies *(other packages required for that package to work)*, you can get them from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas/alphabetical). Look for ones for `12.04` or `precise`, as I think that is what you are using from your given info. You can install those as above.

Comment: First of all thanks very much for the replies.  it is really appreciated.
I had a go at installing all four packages.  They all worked ok, except rfkill, which gave me the following message:
     -ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
So, i rebooted and then first thing i did was run the rfkill list all script.  But I got nothing, so tried to install again, and got the same message at the end.  This time i didn;t reboot and just ran the script, only to again get nothing.  See more comments below. For some reason I can't add a proper reply :s

Comment: salvador@salvador:~$ rfkill list all
[nothing]
salvador@salvador:~$ sudo dpkg -i '/media/WHITIE/rfkill_0.4-1ubuntu2_i386.deb' 
[sudo] password for salvador: 
(Reading database ... 496075 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace rfkill 0.4-1ubuntu2 (using .../rfkill_0.4-1ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement rfkill ...
Setting up rfkill (0.4-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
salvador@salvador:~$ rfkill list all
[nothing]

Comment: I ran previous scripts for lshw and ethtool and got some answers - see below.  Hopefully they will assist with working out what is missing on my pc.  

--------------------------

salvador@salvador:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[first it shows] CPUID
[but quickly turns to ] PCI (sysfs)  
[but after a few seconds, it turns to nothing]

--------------------------

salvador@salvador:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[same as above]

Comment: salvador@salvador:~$ sudo ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
 Supported ports: [ MII ]
 Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                         1000baseT/Full 
 Supported pause frame use: No
 Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
 Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                         1000baseT/Full 
 Advertised pause frame use: No
 Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
 Speed: Unknown!
 Duplex: Unknown! (255)
 Port: MII
 PHYAD: 1
 Transceiver: external

Comment: Auto-negotiation: on
 Supports Wake-on: g
 Wake-on: g
 Link detected: no
Once again, thanks you very much for your help thus far and your very clear instructions.  they made me feel like I knew what i was doing... haha, i know u r probably laughing out loud :)

Comment: Your doing OK so far ;-), but could you add the command outputs to your question - they are barely readable. The relevant one would probably be `lshw -C network`, but if that does not work, use `lspci -v`, and look for anything related to `Network`. Please don't post all of it, and use the `code` formatting.